# ng touch equivalent in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I was getting initial forms fields as red when specified them as required and css was

```
 input:invalid
{
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px red;
}
```

I want to highlight them only when they are touched in vanilla javascript.

Comment: what do you mean by touch? Like once focused and if left empty then?

Comment: After once focused and then empty it should be red, but it is showing me initially red.

Comment: are you doing it on email field with :invalid? Actually what invalid does is until it is valid so it show the border (as initially field is empty). You can assign a class to the field if input field is empty or not. Would that work?

Comment: I am using a normal text field input with a required constraint. Are u implying I add a class using jquery?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Even you can use js if you don't want to use jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You should listen to the [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event) event of the input and then listen to the [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) event. After the blur event you should apply a class like "touched" to the input which you have to use as a selector in your CSS.

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

function blurred(event) {
    event.target.classList.add("touched");
  event.target.removeEventListener("blur", blurred);
}

function focused(event) {
  event.target.removeEventListener("focus", focused);
  event.target.addEventListener("blur", blurred);
}

function registerTouch(input) {
    input.addEventListener("focus", focused);
}

for (const input of inputs) {
    registerTouch(input);
}
```

```css
input.touched:invalid
{
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px red;
}
```

```html
<form id="registration-form">
  <input type="text" id="name" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can edit the pseudo element CSS rule directly with JS without touching a stylesheet with [insertRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule)/[addRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) but I would probably toggle a classname on blur.

[demo](https://jsbin.com/vayenopibi/edit?html,output)

```css
/* css */
input:invalid {
   box-shadow: none;
}
input.blurred:invalid {
   box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px red;
}
```

```js
// js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')

for(let input of inputs){
    input.addEventListener('focus', ()=>{
        input.classList.remove('blurred')
    })
    input.addEventListener('blur', ()=>{
        input.classList.add('blurred')
    })
}
```